# How to use any button as a variable in a method?

Tags: java

I have different buttons with different in different groups in a JFrame Form and I want to create a method that lets me use any of them. The VarButton would get the button it's supposed to operate like Button1 and then I write VarButton.setEnabled() and it enables Button1. I tried it with getName and setName but it didn't work.

Comment: If I've understood your intent clearly, what you want should be easily possible.  Could you show the code you tried?

Comment: You can access the button that was clicked by using the `getSource()` method of the `ActionEvent` in your `ActionListener`.

Comment: Please don't deface your question. Once you ask a question on this site, your question and its code becomes property of the site as per the terms of service that you agreed to on joining the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it sounds like you are coming from Android where you do stuff like `R.id.button_id`. But in java it is much more simple. Just use a parameter of the class Button:

```
public void yourMethod(JButton varButton)
{
    VarButton.setEnabled();
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
JButton button1 = new JButton("Hello");
yourMethod(button1);
```